# Where to add HTML elements?

Tags: sapui5

Where do we generally add HTML elements like `<div>` or `<p>` in SAPUI5?

Do we add them in the index.html or inside the XML view? I am taking the OpenSAPUI5 course of developing apps with SAPUI5 and there they advice to group UI elements in views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply don't. SAP UI5 does not support insertion of HTML elements in its UI structure.

You either need to use the 'HTML' control, or develop a custom control that will build your HTML content.

edit : https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/be/54950cae1041f59d4aa97a6bade2d8/content.htm

Comment: Thank you. Which is used generally the HTML control with content property or defining the custom control with namespace pointing to html of w3 ?

Comment: Actually depends on your need (there are few to no valid reasons to insert HTML directly :p)

Comment: seems like I was wrong : https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/be/54950cae1041f59d4aa97a6bade2d8/content.htm

Comment: Thank you Ash. I am new to SAPUI5 and need to develop an online questionnaire frontend with SAPUI5 .